# How to assign a name to an anonymous gulp (v4) task

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-task

I am using gulp for the first time now and followed the recommendation of [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks) and exported my gulp tasks.

It is running and the results are as expected. However on my console, the tasks are listed as .

How can I assign a name to exported gulp tasks?

I have been trying to follow different approaches, such as functionName.displayName = "Custom Name"; before exporting the module, but nothing worked.

Sample gulp file.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const createHtml = require('./scripts/createHtml');
...

module.export = {
    default: gulp.series(createHtml())
}
```

createHtml module

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
...

const createHtml = function () {
    return function () {
        return gulp
            .src('./src/pages/**/*.+(html)')
            ... 
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/')))
    };
}
createHtml.displayName = "Custom Name";

module.exports = createHtml;
```

gulp output

```
[11:38:50] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/.../gulpfile.js
[11:38:50] Starting 'default'...
[11:38:50] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[11:38:50] Finished '<anonymous>' after 10 ms
[11:38:50] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[11:38:50] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[11:38:50] Finished '<anonymous>' after 24 ms
[11:38:50] Finished '<anonymous>' after 42 ms
...
```

I am using the following versions:

- gulp v4.0.2
- node v15.2.0
- macOS 11.5.1

Comment: `function () {` what about giving these functions a name? `function myFunctionName () {`. They're both anonymous at the moment

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you. Unfortunately this doesn't work either.

Comment: @ingoBe i think i have the answer, please try that. i'm using gulp v4 and it showing the task name in console. so give it a try. posting answer in a minute

Comment: @evolutionxbox I misunderstood your answer at fist. Returning a named function indeed works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @ingoBe no worries. It was a suggestion not an answer. I'll let Gulam answer it if they like --- also please do not edit the question with the answer (in case you felt the need to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to return a function from `createHtml` function. you are returning anonymous function and that anonymous is being executed in `gulp.series()` call, that's why task name is anonymous.

You need to pass named function to `gulp.series`.

Try this -

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
...

const createHtml = function () {
     return gulp.src('./src/pages/**/*.+(html)')
     ... 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/')))
}

module.exports = createHtml;
```

Then in your gulp file

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const createHtml = require('./scripts/createHtml');
...

module.export = {
    default: gulp.series(createHtml);// pass the function reference here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! If I add ```return``` before gulp.src(...).pipe(...), it works and I even can omit the createHtml.displayName line.

Comment: Yes yes, you don't need `createHtml.displayName = "Custom Name"`. updating the answer

Comment: I think ```return``` inside```'const createHtml = function () {}``` is necessary for this to work? Otherwise the task can't be completed. At least in my case.